# numberpicker widget and holoeverywhere missing theme

Tags: android, themes, android-holo-everywhere

I'm trying to get [Simons](http://web-agent.appspot.com/github.com/SimonVT/android-timepicker) Number Picker to work together with [Holoeverywhere](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere). however holoeverwhere requires me to set `android:theme="@style/Holo.Theme"` whereas the number picker requires `android:theme="@style/SampleTheme.Light"`. I'm not very familiar with styles and themes yet, what are my options? Right now the number picker displays incorrectly:

[image: holoeverywhere and numberpicker]

PS. I need backwards comp. till 2.2 and would prefer keeping the holo theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a built in NumberPicker in HoloEverywhere.

You can test it with the demo application.

```
org.holoeverywhere.widget.NumberPicker
```

Here is a link to the source code:

*https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere/blob/master/library/src/org/holoeverywhere/widget/NumberPicker.java*

MOVED TO: https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/blob/master/library/src/org/holoeverywhere/widget/NumberPicker.java

Maybe there is a way to use Simons widget on a dark theme, should be possible.

Comment: that works indeed. I replaced `net.simonvt.widget.NumberPicker`  with `org.holoeverywhere.widget.NumberPicker` and imported `import org.holoeverywhere.widget.NumberPicker`. it's not quite as nice but it works!

Comment: Solution 2 would be to create your own theme with either Holo or simon as parent and add the other theme manually

Comment: the link is broken. Can you fix it?